# Wrap existing array in List without copying or reflection?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

In our C# application we sometimes need to convert plain T[] arrays to List, and often these arrays are extremely large. The normal List(IEnumerable) constructor *copies* the existing collection into a new array backing field in the list. We don't want to waste the memory/clock cycles to do this.

Is there a way to take an existing array T[] and wrap a list around it without copying the array?

I know you can use reflection and directly manipulate List's backing field array, but this would be sensitive to changes in the .NET implementation of List and would be very fragile.

Comment: Can you use interfaces instead? Like `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`? This is one of the use case those interfaces are designed to solve. Another recent additions are `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>`.

Comment: In short - no. Consider either using `IReadOnlyList<T>` or creating your own `IList<T>` implementation.

Comment: Why do you need to convert an array to a list? What do you need to do that you can't do with an array?

Comment: What @GuruStron said; the answer is "no". However, there are a lot of list-like things that will work *without any work* in place of `List<T>` *and a lot of other types* here, allowing you to abstract away the specific implementation details: `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` etc, `[ReadOnly]Memory<T>`, `[ReadOnly]Span<T>`, etc

Comment: @GuruStron actually OP explicitly said that in the question and I completely missed that part :(... (Updated title to say "without reflection")

Comment: it depends on what operations you need to perform on the "list". as @MarcGravell suggested, i think types like ```[ReadOnly]Span<T>``` and ```[ReadOnly]Memory<T>``` could possibly work. Spans represent contiguous regions of arbitrary memory. For example, you could cast an array to a read-only Span like so: ```ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };```.

Comment: You realize that any list-y operations you'd subsequently do (Add, Remove, etc); would also require copying the array right?

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion hypothetically, if you *did* create a list from a pre-existing array: then certainly `Add` would copy (because we know the backing array - our original array - would be full), but `Remove` wouldn't

Comment: @MarcGravell ok sure remove won't always copy the whole array but on average it'll copy half of it. Point is there seems like little point in doing this rather than just refactoring whatever is expecting a `List` to take an array instead.

Comment: Also `T[]` automatically implements `IList<T>` although collection modifying operations will fail. However simple accessor operations will be fine. So if you're able to refactor whatever is expecting `List<T>` to accept `IList<T>` and you don't care about insert/remove/etc then that would be your best bet. If you do need to do listy operations then you might as well just eat the performance hit and use `ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In this case, an API we don't have much control over returns an array to us. We subsequently want to remove items from it, which is why we want a list. We are stuck on .NET Framework so no access to Span. In our case we're not too concerned with order in the array, so we use a "FastRemove()" method on List<T> that takes the last item in the last and places it at the index you want to remove. The end result is, while it changes the order of items in the list, you avoid shuffling all the following indices down by one so it's very fast.